# tensorflow validation monitor streaming auc

Tags: python, tensorflow

In `tensorflow` validation monitor streaming auc, what does it mean for streaming?

Suppose we set `every_n_steps = 100` so the monitor will be called every 100 steps.

Also, suppose the input_fn function for the validation monitor will yield a streaming of data. Let's assume 10 batches.

Case 1: the auc state is reset every time the validation monitor is called, there for, the streaming is done for the 10 batches in each validation step.

Case 2: the auc state is NOT reset, so the streaming auc is computed from the first call of validation monitor. Namely, the first output (at 100 steps) is computed from 10 batches, the second validation output (at 200 steps) is computed based on the streaming auc after the first call and also the 10 batches fed in. The third output (at 300 steps) is computed based on the streaming auc after the second call and also the 10 batches fed in.

Question1, which one of the scenarios is implemented?

Question2, if we use `tf.metrics.auc`, what is the difference? In [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc) they say:

> For estimation of the metric over a stream of data, the function creates an update_op operation that updates these variables and returns the auc.

so this also computes the streamed auc?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Case 1. `ValidationMonitor` calls an Estimator's evaluate(), which reloads the model from a checkpoint. Local variables, which include the statistics that Metrics hang on to, are not saved in checkpoints; they are re-initialized from scratch after the checkpoint is reloaded.

Metrics are always streaming so that multiple evaluation steps (as controlled by the `eval_steps` argument to `ValidationMonitor`) can be combined. But this aggregation is only within an `evaluate()` step.

As for `tf.contrib.streaming_auc` vs `tf.metrics.auc`, the latter is in core TensorFlow and has API stability guarantees (it was probably moved there after hanging out in `contrib` as `streaming_auc` for a bit). They should be equivalent, and the core version is preferable unless the `contrib` version gets some fancy new feature you want to use (not applicable here).